# Bloquear acesso a arquivos javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, htaccess

Tenho um arquivo javascript que faz requisições ajax pra minha API só que eu não quero que ninguém descubra o link dela há alguma forma de bloquear o acesso a este arquivo ?

Se não tem alguma forma de liberar para somente o site poder acessar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No momento que a requisição AJAX é realizada, sempre será possível rastrear.
Pois, a origem da requisição é feita no cliente. Logo, o que pode ser feito é fazer uma validação no servidor.

Exemplo:

Vamos supor que você está fazendo a requisição do site: http://www.testandoapi.com.br/index.php

No arquivo index.php, você pode ter uma instrução em PHP que verifica se a origem da requisição é www.testandoapi.com.br.

```
<?php
  if( $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] === 'www.testandoapi.com.br' ){ 
     //seu codigo aqui
  }
?>
```

Isso fará que somente requisições vindas do domínio www.testandoapi.com.br, sejam executadas.

Obs.: A solução acima não é imune a falhas, existe outras vertentes que devem ser levadas em consideração.

---

Complementando a solução acima, você pode trabalhar com `Token` também.
Mas para isso, será necessário definir alguns critérios:

1. Se vai ou não gerar o `Token`, para todos que acessarem o site.
2. A periodicidade do `Token`.

Pode ter outros itens a definir, vale levar em consideração o contexto que sua API vai ser utilizada.

Comment: Consegui já fiz bem isso $site_ = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

Comment: Apesar da solução, não acho nada confiável fazer dessa forma. Principalmente porque normalmente quem vai querer fazer requisição vai ser uma pessoa experiente e que facilmente consegue burlar isso.

Comment: SERVER_NAME recupera o nome do servidor e não os dados da requisição. Vale dar uma olhada em HTTP_HOST e HTTP_ORIGIN.

Vê se isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name

Comment: É algo simples acho que ninguém tentará burlar :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, concordo com você. Para criar uma solução mais elegante, teríamos que entender o porque dessa segurança e o contexto da API e sua utilização.

Comment: Eu criaria um `Token` único e passaria sempre na requisição, é mais seguro do que simplesmente verificar um campo texto na requisição

Comment: Boa... Mas para o Token funcionar teria que ter uma regra bem estabelecida de  criação e leitura do mesmo. Por que, dar um Token e deixar aberto a todos, daria no mesmo que fazer a validação de um campo texto na requisição...

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, adicionei sua sugestão na resposta... ;)

Comment: @GustavoCarvalho Grato :)

Comment: HTTP_ORIGIN é um recurso novo oferecido pelo Google Chrome.. Outros browsers não suportam. Além do mais, não reconhecido por servidores.. é preciso instalar um módulo específico para suporte. O problema maior é, o efeito é o mesmo de HTTP_REFERER. Pode ser manipulado facilmente. E mais um problema ainda maior, numa requisição legítima, o valor de HTTP_ORIGIN ou HTTP_REFERER pode vir vazio. Então estaria bloqueando uma requisição legítima. 
O JavaScript precisa ser lido de qualquer forma. Tudo que tentar fazer para bloquear o acesso é em vão. No máximo, vc pode dificultar com obfuscação.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve prover segurança no lado servidor, autorizando somente quem possa ter acesso a ação do endereço. O "link" pode ser descoberto de qualquer maneira quando for feita a requisição do usuário, bastando o interessado monitorar as requisições no próprio navegador.